# Cookie alternative that gets stored forever

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, browser

I've read in Hacker News the other day there is a way to store some values in user's browser without using Cookie and this apparently cannot get deleted by the users.

I forgot what this is now and was wondering if anyone knew what this was?

Comment: If it's on the user's computer, it can be deleted by the user. You think you can store something that will survive a disk reformat?

Comment: What you're probably thinking of is LocalStorage.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"cannot get deleted by the user" is impossible. If you set it, it can be deleted.

That said, there has been discussion recently about using [ETag headers for tracking](http://yro.slashdot.org/story/13/08/25/1521233/cookieless-web-tracking-using-https-etag), which will only get erased when the user clears their cache (not when they delete cookies).

There's also the the localStorage stuff that's part of the HTML5 spec: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html